# Best way to declare an array of NSInteger in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the header file I want to declare an array of NSInterger, what's the best way to do that?
I try this code, but it lead to an error

```
@interface test:NSObject
{
}
@property(nonatomic,readwrite)NSInteger f[4]={1,2,3,4}; // Error!!!
@end
```

Comment: you do not initialize a property in the header do it in the implementation file specifically in the `init` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this; instead initialize the array in the object's `init` method and provide a custom setter/getter:

Header:

```
@interface test:NSObject
{
    NSInteger _f[4];
}
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger *f;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation test

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _f[0] = 1;
        _f[1] = 2;
        _f[2] = 3;
        _f[3] = 4;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger *)f {
    return _f;
}

- (void)setF:(NSInteger *)f {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        _f[i] = f[i];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want an array of NSIntegers? NSIntegers are a primitive type; they are not objects. The usual convention in Objective-C for most use cases would be to store an NSArray of NSNumber objects. A literal number can be converted into an NSNumber by prefixing it with the `@` symbol.

In your header:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myArray;
```

In your `init` method or similar:

```
self.myArray = @[ @1, @2, @3, @4 ];
```

Comment: And how to get the values in this way?

Comment: To retrieve values, you can access elements like you would a normal C array: `NSNumber *number = self.myArray[0];`. Note that if you want a primitive `NSInteger` value back (rather than an `NSNumber` object), you'll need to call `integerValue` on the number: `[number integerValue];`.

Answer (score 0):

int array[100];
create it as a global variable.

In your .m file add it after,

```
@interface MyClass ()

@end

@implementation MyClass{
}
int a[] ={1,2,34};
```

-(void)init{,.....

Try to NSLog(@"%d",a[1]), it will print perfectly.

Comment: But I want to put some values directly to the array? int array[100]={1,2,3,4} lead to error too?

Comment: int array[]={1,2,3,4}. this way sir.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working, my question in Objective-c !

Comment: you can write c and c++code in objective C. updated the answer, try it once.

Comment: +1 for oldschool solution. I use it often by myself.

Comment: mee too, most of the algos if i need to use, i write them in c.